# how do i split the unstructured data and insert it into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do i split the unstructured data and insert it into a table

the below data represents unstructured data which i need to format in a set of different column and insert it in a table,

```
ABB0512  709023378812005327020220953171        025336141992033270207033123002663270200401ABC02055       ABC02055CBL MURARJIPET,MALAD MAlAD      MHIN3270204     ABC                                                          333000000000050000000000000050000000000000000000333000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000

ABB0222  709023378812005327020220953171    025222141992033270207033123002663270200401PQR02055       PQR02055CBL MURARJIPET,THANE THANE      MHIN3270204     PQR                                                          222000000000010000000000000010000000000000000000222000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000
```

The structure of the data after formatting will be as show below :

```
----a---------b------------c---------------------d-----e
========================================================================
ABC02055    ABC02055    CBL MURARJIPET,MALAD    MAlAD   MHIN

PQR02055    PQR02055    CBL MURARJIPET,THANE    THANE   MHIN
```

The below query gives the expected result for just the first string

```
Declare @variablestring varchar(max)
set @variablestring = substring(@strval,0,407)
print @variablestring
INSERT INTO tbldummyEntries(A, B, C,D,E,F)
values( CAST(SUBSTRING(@variablestring, 84, 15) AS Varchar(MAX)) ,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(@variablestring, 99, 8) AS Varchar(MAX)) ,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(@variablestring, 107, 22) AS Varchar(MAX)),
    CAST (SUBSTRING(@variablestring, 130, 13) AS Varchar(MAX)),
    CAST (SUBSTRING (@variablestring, 143, 5) AS Varchar(MAX)),
    CAST (SUBSTRING(@variablestring , 148 , 261) AS Varchar(MAX)))
set @strval=REPLACE(@strval,@variablestring,'')
```

How do i replicate it for the entries following after the first one?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use substring function to split the data row.

Comment: Think how you would do this manually, and then translate that into operations in a query.

Comment: If you actually list the rules required and show some effort (post a query) I'm sure we'll be happy to help.... or someone might just help anyway. For starters - have you already loaded this into a table as-is? don't keep us guesing

Comment: i have tried using the substring function but don't know how to replicate it for futher entries. Have made the edit with the queries i have tried till now !

Comment: Were is the unstructured data now? In a table? Or in a text file? Often I just use some text editor or even Excel to create my insert statement from textual data.

Comment: unstructured data is in a text file. i have just posted 2 entries while the text file contains 100's of them.

Comment: you can bulk insert your file using WITH FORMATFILE  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql. To create format file use this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516(v=SQL.90).aspx. Of course, sql server must have read access to data file and format file, most probably you can't import file from user profile

Comment: Is your data actually fixed width - are fields always in the same position? Your sample data says no but your code attempt says yes. Some very basic explanation of the file format is required

Answer (score 0):

I tried as follows:(Keep the length in loop as per your format)

```
Declare @variablestring varchar(max),@strval varchar(max)
set @strval='ABB0512  709023378812005327020220953171        025336141992033270207033123002663270200401ABC02055       ABC02055CBL MURARJIPET,MALAD MAlAD      MHIN3270204     ABC                                                          333000000000050000000000000050000000000000000000333000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000

ABB0222  709023378812005327020220953171    025222141992033270207033123002663270200401PQR02055       PQR02055CBL MURARJIPET,THANE THANE      MHIN3270204     PQR                                                          222000000000010000000000000010000000000000000000222000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000'
set @variablestring = substring(@strval,0,407)
while len(@strval)>406
begin
INSERT INTO tbldummyEntries(A, B, C,D,E,F) values
select CAST(SUBSTRING(@variablestring, 84, 15) AS Varchar(MAX)) ,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(@variablestring, 99, 8) AS Varchar(MAX)) ,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(@variablestring, 107, 22) AS Varchar(MAX)),
    CAST (SUBSTRING(@variablestring, 130, 13) AS Varchar(MAX)),
    CAST (SUBSTRING (@variablestring, 143, 5) AS Varchar(MAX)),
    CAST (SUBSTRING(@variablestring , 148 , 261) AS Varchar(MAX))
set @strval=REPLACE(@strval,@variablestring,'')
set @variablestring = substring(@strval,0,407)
    end
```